# What is wrong with this XML file?

Tags: xml

:: link to xml file removed

View Source in Firefox... I don't see anything out of place.

I don't know if this is any good but I ran it through this.

http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/

Seems to suggest characters before the document? However.. these aren't  visible when viewing the source of the document.

Deleted his site and replaced with a working copy to ensure no files had been tampered with / corrupted. Issue persists.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a sequence of 8 non-displayable bytes at the start of the stream, before the opening `<?`. Some parsers aren't going to like that.

Both Firefox and Chrome reject it as an XML document, but their source viewers strip out the leading bytes, so it looks fine.

Comment: What are NUL characters? This is a really old system and loads like 30 files to make a small XML file. Are these spaces?

Comment: @JasonS: Not spaces, no, they're bytes with an ASCII value of zero. hard to say why they're there without looking at the code in `data.php`

Comment: @JasonS NUL characters have ASCII value 0. Spaces have ASCII value 32. Your text editor ought to be displaying these characters to you in some manner, and it should have a hex editing mode that shows you their character code. You can then delete them. (If it doesn't, then you need a better text editor.)

Comment: Found an odd red diamond in file 21. Deleted it and tada! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first 8 characters are NUL characters.  Try removing them.